# Buddhism Open Activities for all communities

Tags: monk, food

I am not sure this post is appropriate.

[image]

Pindacāra, the practice of collecting alms-food, is observed by Theravada Buddhist monks who have gone forth from ‘home-life’ to ‘homelessness’. A Buddhist monk is known in Pāli Language as a ‘bhikkhu’ – meaning ‘one who lives on alms’.

In Buddhist countries such as Thailand and Myanmar, it is a daily ritual for monks to go on Pindacāra, where they walk through a village from one household to another, allowing devotees to make food offerings.

Q) Why it mentions all are welcome except Muslim? I understand some non halal food served in between of the activities. What would be the right wording so it's sound better but deliver the same message?

Comment: Bhikku - means Bhawa + Kshaya. Someone who is reducing 'bhawa'. If Bhikku means 'one who lives on alms' that would encompass anyone who lives on alms and most of the homeless community. Your definition is wrong.

Comment: @Sampath i did copy paste from here. Perhaps u can report to them. Sadhu. https://www.nalanda.org.my/pindacara-going-on-alms-round/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is valid, and you thought it is related to Buddhism, but actually it's not.

In some Muslim majority countries like [Malaysia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_religion_in_Malaysia#Proselytising), it is illegal to proselytize or convert Muslims to other religions, or cause them to apostatize. Due to this, when non-Muslim religious and/or spiritual organizations organize public events, they would add "[For non-Muslims only](https://bgf.org.my/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/2021-06-14-Ven-Dhammika-1024x576.jpg)" to their posters, as a formality.

The same applies to businesses selling products and services that are considered to be in conflict with Islam, like casinos, lotteries and [yoga lessons](https://pkglobal.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/no-muslim-yoga-sign.jpg).

There is nothing in Buddhism that restricts the lay participation of non-Buddhists in Buddhist events.

Comment: I checked with Malaysian Muslim NGO (Non Profit Organization). If event like giving free food can label with "Non Halal Food Provided, For Halal Food Please contact ### for reservation instead of "For non Muslim Only" then get the Muslim NGO join the event too. The Muslim NGO better be a well known one. If anything happen, can look for that Muslim NGO first. It's not been easy in multi-racial country.

Comment: @littlestar Really? I found [this news article](https://www.thestar.com.my/news/nation/2021/12/24/zulkifli-gurdwara-food-is-halal) which may be of interest to you.